# Will an overstay in Ecuador affect my Canada student visa application?

Tags: visas, canada, overstaying, ecuador

I am from India. I overstayed for one month in Ecuador on a tourist visa, but the Immigration officer gave me an exit stamp without any problem. If I apply for a student visa to Canada, will this overstay be a problem?